# Fast list generation from the narrow data.frame

Tags: r, performance, lapply

I have a data.frame in the narrow format like that:

```
test_data<-data.frame(id=rep(1:200,50), 
variable=sample(LETTERS,10000,T), 
value=sample(letters,10000,T), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to get a list containing lists for each id with each variable as a vector inside (something like simple JSON format):

```
list("1"=list(A=c("a","b"), B=character(), C="v" ...
```

My code:

```
return_data <-
   sapply(unique(test_data$id), function (r)
      sapply(LETTERS, function(q)
        test_data[test_data$id == r & test_data$variable == q, "value"],
      USE.NAMES = T,simplify = F),
    USE.NAMES = T,simplify = F)
```

It works, but it is too slow with large samples. I've rewritten it with data. table, but it is still slow. I've got some improvement with parSapply, but I believe there should be more effective algorithm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split` with `variable` being a factor, thanks to the `drop = FALSE` behavior (on by default but passed explicitly here for readability). With magrittr:

```
library(magrittr)

res = test_data %>% 
  transform(variable = factor(variable)) %>% 
  split(.["id"]) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) split(x$value, x["variable"], drop = FALSE))

all.equal(unname(res), return_data) # TRUE
```

The same without magrittr:

```
new_test_data = transform(test_data, variable = factor(variable))
sp_id = split(new_test_data , new_test_data["id"])
res2 = lapply(sp_id, function(x) split(x$value, x["variable"], drop = FALSE))

all.equal(unname(res2), return_data) # TRUE
```

Comment: Perfect! It works 0.5 sec per 100k-row table splitting, it is 100 times faster!